# Link inside Polymer core-tooltip

Tags: polymer

How to add a link inside "rich" core-tooltip?

This example is not working:

```
<core-tooltip large>
  <div class="rich">Rich tooltip with HTML </div>
  <div tip>
     Test link:    <a href="http://www.polymer-project.org/" target="_blank">Polymer</a>
  </div></core-tooltip>
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qasafohaqizu/2/watch?html,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's  an issue with the "pointer-events" property of the polymer-tooltip class.
Overwriting it should help. I'm gonna open issue for this on github.
https://github.com/Polymer/core-tooltip/blob/master/core-tooltip.css

EDIT:
Issue was fixed here: https://github.com/Polymer/core-tooltip/commit/c894b1e1f3efa51068ac78c8703d5be059c13c78#diff-9d330d77a70dbe6ddc82a0dbc4ac3b62
Bower sync should do the job, release is 0.4.0.